# Firebase Analytics not counting users anymore

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

My Firebase Analytics just stopped working some time ago, it just says 0 users each single day, despite I have several daily active users.

This is my dependency I am using (Will I have to use Firebase Core as well? I've once read that it's not needed. Might the removal of that happened to be the issue?)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
```

On top this is what I have in my AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT"
        android:value="true"/>

    <!-- Google Play Services -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
```

I then launch Firebase Analytics with this line:

```
 FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

I am not logging anything, I just have this line of code as I don't need more. I've downloaded a fresh google-services.json file however since yesterday the Analytics Dashboard says 0 users.